# sty file is already included but the error message showed that is not found. why?

Tags: pdftex, journal-publishing

```
! LaTeX Error: File `ecrc.sty' not found.
Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)
Enter file name:
! Emergency stop.
<read *>
l.7 ^^M
*** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
2735 strings out of 480681
32117 string characters out of 5908536
266899 words of memory out of 5000000
18590 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
533028 words of font info for 26 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
38i,0n,34p,238b,86s stack positions out of
5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!'
```

.sty file is already included but the error message showed that, is not found. why?

Comment: presumably you did not place the file where tex can find it but you have given no information where you did put it (placing it in the same directory as the document shoudl work for example)

Comment: I found it why, but not the solution.

I should use macro to customize some texts, figures and equations but EM can not process. 

" EM cannot process LaTeX files with macros. Macros are not recognized by the software that
EM’s PDF builders use to compile LaTeX submissions. Do not submit LaTeX files containing
macros, even if your local TeX installation uses macros."

Any method to resolve this issue ?

Thanks in advanced

Comment: That is presumably your other question, Do you want to delete this one?